# Analogy between group theoretic number theory proofs and function fields

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, function-fields

We know that it is possible to prove some number theoretic congruences by using group theoretic tools like Burnside's Lemma for orbit counting. Many of these congruences also hold for $F[x]$ where $F$ is a finite field. Is it possible to generalise group theoretic tools to prove such congruences in $F[x]$?